# How do I enclose an Excel cell contents with parentheses for an entire column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel document with data needs to be enclosed with parentheses.

data for 1 cell would look like:

> 1234,'2000-01-01',3750000.000000,3750000.000000,3750000.000000,3750000.000000,0

I want it to look like:

> (1234,'2000-01-01',3750000.000000,3750000.000000,3750000.000000,3750000.000000,0)

This would need to be for an entire column though. Sounds like a macro might be the best way to do this though I am not sure.

Comment: Assuming your data is in column A, simply put this formula in column B. Then drag down: "="("&A1"&")".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example for column **B**:

```
Sub parens()
   Dim r As Range

   For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
      If r.Text <> "" Then
         r.Value = "(" & r.Text & ")"
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was needing. I didnt even know this was what I needed until I used it :) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to do this for a single column, and don't mind adding a new column to the sheet, the "concatenate" function can do this job rather well too.

Example:

```
=Concatenate("(",A2,")")
```

Then all you need to do is click the bottom right corner of the cell and drag to the bottom of the column.  Copying and pasting works well too of course.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt use this method but I did make a note as I can use this in another area of this workbook.